# Why flutter image picker is so slow, and how to fix it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-image-picker

I am using `image_picker` flutter package, and not very happy with its performance. Picking any video above two minute is very slow. It can easily take over 30 seconds while the application seemingly freezes, and then goes through picking the image.

I don't really understand how it is related to the video size, as it shouldn't really read the file but to simply give me a handler, but it seems it does!

I couldn't find a way to fix it, or work around it, or even at least show a spinner or something else beside a frozen gallery with no success.

It is actually very easy to reproduce, just run the sample in the image_picker, and pick a 4 min video.

Has anyone found a way to make a tolerable user experience for this?